# android java inheritance

Tags: java, android, inheritance

I have a class named `Chat` which extends `Activity`.

When I'm creating the `Chat` class, I'm saving a reference to it in the `Application` class.

```
onCreate(Bundle) {
    setCurrentActivity(this);
}
```

I want to enter the the Chat area of the activity, in order to use one of its methods.
I'm trying to do it like this:

```
Chat chat = (Chat) getCurrentActivity();
chat.someUniqueFuction();
```

but I can't see any `Chat` methods. Why?

Comment: I don't quite understand, but I don't see why you need ot save a reference to the class in the class? You have the keyword "this." Where is this chat.someUniqueFunction() being called from?

Comment: its really a bad idea to save a reference of your activity even when it is not required. This may tend to memory leaks.

Comment: Please provide the class\method signatures of Chat, Activity, and Application. From the code you've provided its hard to answer your question.

Comment: You should re-read Android basics. Unless you explain why you are taking this approach, this is really wrong.

Comment: its a metaphoric class.. if i have a chat class which extends activity class, and i have the activity class saved, in which syntax should i call the chat class part of the activity ? it is something i don't understand in inheritance

Comment: ok guys actually it's my stupid mistake... my function was set to private... my apologize...

Answer (score 0):

In the **Application** class it should look like this

```
public void onCreate(){
    super.onCreate();
    setCurrentActivity(this);
}
```

And this would not have the wished effect because you would set your Application which is no Activity as **currentActivity**.

Answer (score 0):

```
onCreate(Bundle saveInstance){
   super.onCreate();
   Chat chat = new Chat();
   chat.someUniqueFuction();
}
```